# How to add the JavaFX examples to netbeans and adapt the platform?

Tags: java, javafx, platform, netbeans-8

I try to load the javafx examples on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html 
to netbeans. I have loaded them but every time I start a java-File, I always get this error. I have no idea how to handle the platform property....
Thanks a lot

*ant -f C:\JavaBeispiele\javafx-samples-2.2.79\src\Ensemble jfxsa-run
C:\JavaBeispiele\javafx-samples-2.2.79\src\Ensemble\nbproject\build-impl.xml:88: The J2SE Platform is not correctly set up.
 Your active platform is: default_platform, but the corresponding property "platforms.default_platform.home" is not found in the project's properties files. 
 Either open the project in the IDE and setup the Platform with the same name or add it manually.
 For example like this:
     ant -Duser.properties.file= jar (where you put the property "platforms.default_platform.home" in a .properties file)
  or ant -Dplatforms.default_platform.home= jar (where no properties file is used)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
:*

Comment: [`javafx-samples-2.2.80`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) looks newer.

Comment: I think a very similar problem (with the same solution) is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455793/the-j2se-platform-is-not-correctly-set-up-netbeans-ide-8-0-2/48418101#48418101

Answer (score 0):

I managed it by myself. I went to Projekt Properties and Librairies. There I added a new platform. In my Java-Ordner I copied jdk1.8 and renamed it to platforms.defauld_platform.home and this platform i